# Telebot. Как отправить сообщение и перейти по ссылке после нажатия кнопки?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Код:

```
def start(message):
       markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 1)
       button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="BMW", callback_data="BMW", url = 'site') 
       button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Audi", callback_data="Audi") 
       markup.add(button1, button2)
       bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="Какую марку хочеш?", reply_markup=markup)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def longname(call):
    if call.data == "BMW":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text="рандомный текст")
```

После нажатия на BMW, переходит по ссылке, но не печатает `рандомный текст`. Как можно исправить?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос, если вы хотите чтобы бот переходил по своей же ссылке, тогда можно использовать webbrowser. webbrowser.open('url')

Comment: попробуйте открывать ссылку уже после рандомного текста